# How to make the code wait for receiving a signal in qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots

I have a `gui` class and another class named `guiThread`. The `gui` class starts `guiThread` as a thread that communicates with `gui` with the help of signals and slots.
I have a slot in `guiThread` named `doAction()` and I have a signal which is send from `gui` class to this slot.
So what I want to do in `guiThread` is that I want to do a while loop that waits until the signal is sent from `gui` to `doAction()` slot and when it recieved the signal, the slot does some calculations.
I dont know how to do this while loop and I dont even know if what I want is possible. I would be appreciate it if somebody could help me.

Comment: What is the purpose of that while loop? Just idly waiting? I think the concept of signal/slot does exactly what you want to do - there is no need for that while loop. Maybe I misunderstand what you are trying to do...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize a private boolean `block=true`, then you wait for the signal by `while(block);`. Whenever you receive the signal, you do your calculations in the corresponding slot, and update `block=false` at the end of it. Thus, when the code returns to the while, it will pass to continue processing.